# Send Email Alert in from Google Sheets when cell value in column is less than 0

Tags: google-sheets

I have no idea how to do this, but would it be possible to send an email alert when a cell value in column G is less than 0?

Here is my spreadsheet. Any assistance would be amazing!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HOXkcYyzEwtLZ3ZGNK1AK8uDZnM9bacrrFH7DR30_Ys/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to grant access to your spreadsheet (anyone with a link, also make sure no senstive information is on it). What have you tried so far? Do you want to send an email when a value in a specific column is below 0 or in the whole sheet? Have you taken a look at [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Google Apps Script Triggers, you can create a trigger that checks the value of the cell every time the sheet is edited or every time span you decide and send you an email.

More info here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable.